# $a, b$ so $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x+1), x>0$ $f(x)= ax+b, x \le 0$ becomes continuous at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

$f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x+1), x>0$

$f(x)= ax+b, x \le 0$

I need to pick $a$ and $b$ so that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. I already found out that $b = 0$. 
My question is if there exists an explicit solution for $a$ or if any value for $a$ is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Find what the limit for the first function is as you go to 0, then set that value equal to the second function and when $x = 0$. Then solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Limit of the first one is $0$ so $ax+0=0$ for any $a$ I guess?

Comment: Any value of $a$ will work.  If you want $f$ to be continuous and differentiable, then you will need to choose the correct value of $a$ as well.

Comment: @dirkpra Yes, $a$ can be any value.

Comment: Ok, to be differentiable $a$ has to be $0$ as well so the left-sided limit equals the right-sided limit in $x=0$, true?

Comment: @dirkpra the derivative of $x^2\sin(1/x+1)$ is $2x\sin(1/x+1)-\cos(1/x+1)$ as $x$ go to $0$ the derivative of either side is undefined, you can't find $a$ that will make $f(x)$ be differentiable at $0$

Comment: I think the limit is defined. Should be $0$

Comment: @dirkpra not it is not, maybe you saw the question wrong and it is $x^3\sin...$?